# Compare Two Values in Same Column

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to compare the value in a single column in a single table. Here is a sample table:

```
ID  Cat     Color
======================
1   red     maroon
2   red     orange
3   red     pink
4   blue    violet
5   blue    purple
6   blue    indigo
7   green   puke green
8   green   hunter green
```

I am given 2 colors from the Color column. I need to know if they belong to the same Cat column. For example, I will be given maroon and orange. I need the value red returned. Violet and purple should return blue. Puke green and violet should return null.

So far I have the following SQL but it's not exactly what I am looking for, especially with the Limit 1. I am looking for a single query to return Cat field without using Limit 1.

```
SELECT Cat
From foo
WHERE 
Color = 'maroon'
and
Color = 'orange'
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: What result do you want if the `cat`s are different? If there are more than 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to [Beginner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30716806/477563), it's possible to solve this problem without a `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT cat
FROM foo
WHERE color IN ('maroon', 'orange')
GROUP BY cat
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
;
```

This works by selecting all cats with the specified colors.  When we group them, the cats that appear multiple times (the `HAVING` clause) are the records you want to keep.

Note: the number using the `HAVING` clause should match the number of colors you're searching for.

Comment: This one is the most reliable. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
SELECT x.cat 
FROM (
  SELECT cat, GROUP_CONCAT(color) AS colors
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY cat) AS x
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('maroon', x.colors) > 0
  AND FIND_IN_SET('orange', x.colors) > 0
```

> **Edit 1:** Another Alternative

```
SELECT IF(
          FIND_IN_SET('maroon', GROUP_CONCAT(color)) > 0 
          AND FIND_IN_SET('orange', GROUP_CONCAT(color)) > 0 , cat, NULL
       ) AS cat
FROM tablename
GROUP BY cat
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Cat varchar(50) = null

select @Cat = Cat
from foo f1
JOIN foo f2 on f1.Cat = f2.Cat
where f1.Color = 'maroon'
and f2.Color = 'orange'

select @Cat
```

Ideally you should have an associated table of colors so that you can do a JOIN and a more specific where.

Comment: Just like the questioner's SQL, this will never return any records. It's like querying where number =1 and number =2.

Comment: Not true, it will return a cat that has a color value of "maroon orange" or "orange maroon" if there is one.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change the structure of the table. I would like to have a more normalized table, but this is what I have.

Comment: The table didn't come out like I had wanted. maroon, orange and pink are all Color values. Their category is red.

Comment: Note how you said "OR" in your comment, but "AND" in the answer.

Comment: I misread the table format in the original question. Need to rethink my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this using `GROUP BY` clause

```
select case when count(*) > 0 then cat else NULL end as MyCat_Column
from (
select Cat
from table1
where color in ('maroon','orange')
group by cat
having count(distinct color) >= 2
) tab;
```

Comment: It needs to return null if the categories are not identical. In your case it is empty result

Answer (score 0):

You need to JOIN the table with itself, on the primary keys of the table (also called Self-Join).

Try this:

```
SELECT A.Cat
From foo A, foo B
WHERE 
A.ID = B.ID 
and A.Cat = B.Cat and
A.Color = 'maroon'
and
B.Color = 'orange'
```